# Remove Duplicate Results from PHP Array From MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, duplicates

I am looking for a way I can remove duplicate values from a PHP array from a resulting MySQL query. What I have so far gives me the query I want but shows any duplicates consistantly. I need to remove them for a navigation menu. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far...

```
$c_search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE interest1 LIKE '%$input%' or interest2 LIKE '%$input%' or interest3 LIKE '%$input%'");
$array = Array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($c_search)) {
array_push($array, $rows['interest1']);
array_push($array, $rows['interest2']);
array_push($array, $rows['interest3']);
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
echo $array[$i] . "\n";
}
}
```

I have tried changing the MySQL query to use DISTINCT, no luck.
I tried using array_unique($array, SORT_STRING), no luck.
Not sure what elese to try. Please help, thanks.

Comment: The problem is probably with your sql query

Comment: Give an example of your final array and your desired array.

Comment: Why isn't `array_unique` working? That's odd.

Comment: DISTINCT would do the trick but depends on where you used it. you need something like `SELECT DISTINCT interest1, DISTINCT interest2... FROM ..... `

Comment: $c_search = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT interest1 FROM members WHERE interest1 LIKE '%$input%'");
 while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($c_search)) {
 $result = $rows['interest1'];
 echo $result . "\n";
} this works for one row query

Comment: array_unique is not showing any results unless if I use array_values to restructure the array, but the results only work if I print_r. I can't echo to make them more user friendly. ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options: create your arrays manually, performing check `if (!in_array($array))`

Comment: I didn't even think of this. Still kinda new to php. But this is great. Also, I did check my MySQL query and it wasn't working. I didn't test it first, too much faith in myself. The DISTINCT works that Lawrence Cherone mentioned. Thanks guys for all your help and quicks responses.